# How can I check what Moovweb project and build number is deployed onto my mobile site?

Tags: mobile, moovweb

Basically, if I'm on my mobile web site, how do I know what project is being used by Moovweb to create that site?

Also, can I check what version/build # of the project I'm currently running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are viewing a live site, you can view the Response Headers of the main page you requested.

There will be the a header called 'X-S-V' and it should list your account name, project name, and build version, along with the git commit hash that it's currently on.

X-S-V: accountname/projectname v1 (4cac14271df72a8d5a0a7f157b09044453e521ba)

If you are viewing a local site, the 'X-S-V' header will be in the form of:

X-S-V: local/directoryname